# elastic search faceted query returns incorrect count

Tags: elasticsearch

I need help in aggregate / faceted queries in elastic search. I have used faceted query to group the results but I’m not getting grouped result with correct count.

Please suggest on how to get grouped results from elastic search.

```
{ 
   "query" : { 
     "query_string" : {"query" : "pared_cat_id:1"} } ,
     "facets" : { 
        "subcategory" : { 
           "terms" : { 
                        "field": "sub_cat_id", 
                         "size" : 50, 
                         "order" : "term", 
                         "all_terms" : true 
                     }
                 } 
           }, 
     "from" : 0, 
     "size": 50 
  }
```

Trying to get grouped results for sub category id for passed parent category id.

Comment: I don't think anyone can help with so few details. At the very least show what query you are running and how the results differ from what you expected. Even better, come up with a small test data set that reproduces the problem

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch faceting queries works very well in terms of accuracy, at least I have not seen any problem yet.
Just a few questions:

1. What field is this string or numeric,give example?
2. Have you applied any custom mapping or you have used default "standard" analyzer

Please state the kind of inaccuracy like `"aa" should have count 100 but its 50` or is there any other kind of inaccuracy?

Comment: Field is integer and inaccuracy in terms of count is like one you have mentioned. If xyz have count 20 its showing 0 or where as if its 126 its showing 60. Have not applied any custom mapping.

Comment: Please post the JSON object which you are trying to index so that I can replicate it at my end.
Which version of ES are you using ?

Comment: 0.18.4. You can ref https://groups.google.com/group/elasticsearch/browse_thread/thread/1bb55debdf45247e/e507058cb424ef2f?lnk=gst&q=facet+count+is+incorrect#e507058cb424ef2f

Comment: {

    "test": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "parent_cat_id": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "sub_cat_id": {
                "type": "long"
            },
        }
    }

}

Comment: The only way for me to verify and suggest any solution is to index the data at my end.I need **sample data** for this. Post a gist

Answer (score 0):

"query_string" : {"query" : "pared_cat_id:1"} } ,

This is applied to overall data and not on the facets counts.

FOr this you need to use facet query in which you can specify same which you are specifying in the main query string.

So facets count which are being shown to you now are based on the results without applying   "query_string" : {"query" : "pared_cat_id:1"} } , ie. to the whole data. Incase you want facets counts after applying   "query_string" : {"query" : "pared_cat_id:1"} } , provide it in the facet query.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch facets query returns incorrect count if the number of shards is >1, so as for now Facets are deprecated and will be removed in a future release. You are encouraged to migrate to aggregations instead.

I suggest that you take a look at [this](https://www.found.no/foundation/elasticsearch-aggregations/) blog post in which Alex Brasetvik give a good description along with some examples on how to use the aggregations feature properly.